# could not find json-1.8.6 in any of the sources

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems

Please help, not sure what i have done wrong. Application has been working up until now but when i run rails server the terminal prints:

> Ignoring binding_of_caller-0.7.2 because its extensions are not built.
>   Try: gem pristine binding_of_caller --version 0.7.2 Ignoring
>   byebug-9.1.0 because its extensions are not built.  Try: gem pristine
>   byebug --version 9.1.0 Ignoring byebug-9.0.6 because its extensions
>   are not built.  Try: gem pristine byebug --version 9.0.6 Ignoring
>   debug_inspector-0.0.3 because its extensions are not built.  Try: gem
>   pristine debug_inspector --version 0.0.3 Ignoring
>   executable-hooks-1.3.2 because its extensions are not built.  Try: gem
>   pristine executable-hooks --version 1.3.2 Ignoring ffi-1.9.18 because
>   its extensions are not built.  Try: gem pristine ffi --version 1.9.18
>   Ignoring gem-wrappers-1.2.7 because its extensions are not built. 
>   Try: gem pristine gem-wrappers --version 1.2.7 Ignoring json-2.1.0
>   because its extensions are not built.  Try: gem pristine json
>   --version 2.1.0 Ignoring json-1.8.6 because its extensions are not built.  Try: gem pristine json --version 1.8.6 Ignoring nokogiri-1.7.2
>   because its extensions are not built.  Try: gem pristine nokogiri
>   --version 1.7.2 Ignoring pg-0.21.0 because its extensions are not built.  Try: gem pristine pg --version 0.21.0 Ignoring pg-0.20.0
>   because its extensions are not built.  Try: gem pristine pg --version
>   0.20.0 Ignoring bcrypt-3.1.11 because its extensions are not built.  Try: gem pristine bcrypt --version 3.1.11 Ignoring
>   binding_of_caller-0.7.2 because its extensions are not built.  Try:
>   gem pristine binding_of_caller --version 0.7.2 Ignoring byebug-9.1.0
>   because its extensions are not built.  Try: gem pristine byebug
>   --version 9.1.0 Ignoring byebug-9.0.6 because its extensions are not built.  Try: gem pristine byebug --version 9.0.6 Ignoring
>   debug_inspector-0.0.3 because its extensions are not built.  Try: gem
>   pristine debug_inspector --version 0.0.3 Could not find json-1.8.6 in
>   any of the sources Run `bundle install` to install missing gems.

i have tried uninstalling and reinstalling gems many time with different versions and still get the same error.

ruby v2.3.3
rails v 4.2.0
macOS Sierra

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Fixed by rebuilding gems with: `gem pristine --all`